# using jquery to select the HTML5 range tracker

Tags: jquery, css

I have a css selector for the html5 range button as this:

```
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track
```

how should i form the jquery selector in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can form it almost exactly as you have it above.

```
var range = $("input[type='range']")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETnbE/

Comment: IIRC, jQuery selectors have all the features CSS selectors have, and some extra's as well. So any CSS selector is a valid jQuery selector, but not *always* the other way around. (Feel free to correct me)

Comment: Not all but most. I believe you can't use `:before` or `:after` and some others.

Comment: Yes, that one is fine. the real problem is how do i get the tracker button i.e ::-moz-range-track .. That's the real problem :P

Comment: Those are pseudo selectors in and of themselves. But good catch nonetheless :)

Comment: @AmanGupta: I recently read that the range input selectors (and similar new input types) are not yet standardized across browsers, much less CSS selectors. Not sure if anything has changed since then, but I suspect there's no surefire way to cover all the browsers at once. But like `box-shadow`, one day it will be :)

Comment: haha.. but yes if you know how can i go about it, 'be really great!
because somehow the css version of the selector isn't catching it. Taken an example that works.. but strangely not when I'm using it

Comment: I'm trying to redesign the range input to make it look like a part of the an existing media player widget. Since I'm working on wordpress and I've tried to add the styles both to the main css file, as well as to the document, nothings happening!

Comment: Yes! that exactly what I'm suing. I just can't understand why this isn't working for me.. the input's in the index.php file and i've added the css to the style.css file in the wordpress template

Comment: @AmanGupta Post your code so we can see what isn't working. Edit your answer with the exact code you are using.

Comment: Oh dear... it was a missing '}' ... ROFL :D
but hey.. good question huh? ;)